# Does newlfm define \InfoPathName?

Tags: letters, newlfm

I'm getting an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \InfoFileName
                  {db.tex}
```

For background `\InfoFileName` is the macro used to change where `newlfm` gets its address information from.

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `newlfm` manual is wrong about this macro. With the minimal example

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\show\InfoFileName
\begin{document} 
\begin{newlfm}
\show\InfoFileName
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

you see that the macro is undefined in both cases. Reading the code of `newlfm.cls` reveals the issue: it is not a *macro* but is instead a key for setting using the `\newlfmP` macro. Try:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\newlfmP{InfoFileName = XXX}
\begin{document} 
\begin{newlfm}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Of course, replace `XXX` here with what you actually need!

Comment: I've reported this as a mistake in the manual