# Adding/subtracting vertical space in »letter« class

Tags: vertical-alignment, letters

Is there a way to move the to-address up (or, respectively, the date down) in the »letter« document class?  With the to-address on the left and date on the right, I wish for the vertical alignment of the top row of the to-address to be the same as that of the date.  Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the source, Luke.  The `letter.cls` file is actually not that hard to read compared to `article.cls` :-)

If you redefine `\opening` you should be able to get what you want:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{%
%  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress
%    \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
%      {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
%  \else  % home address
%    \thispagestyle{empty}%
%    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
%      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
%      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
%  \fi
%  \vspace{2\parskip}%
%  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
    \toname \\ 
    \toaddress
  \end{minipage}\hfill\@date\par
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother
```

The commented-out part is a switch based on whether a from-address is given.  I'm assuming you aren't using a from-address since otherwise you would have specified where you wanted it.

Answer (score 14):

Starting from [Matthew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/adding-subtracting-vertical-space-in-letter-class/5488#5488), I looked in the `letter.cls` file, and I found two values that I manually changed to fit my bill.

*Note that this worked for my single-page, very simple letter; it is not guaranteed to work for you.*

1. Start with this (found somewhere on the internet):

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \let\@texttop\relax
   \makeatother
   ```

   This will reduce the margin a little bit.
2. However, that wasn't enough for me, so I searched in `letter.cls` for the phrase `@texttop`, and found that adding the following changed the margins on the first page to what they are on the rest of the page:

   ```
   \setlength\topmargin{-50pt}
   \setlength\textheight{10in}
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey simple and gut. Thanks it worked wonderfully!

Comment: This seems much better than the accepted answer. Perhaps `addtolength` would be better: `\addtolength\topmargin{-2cm}`.

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at more sophisticated classes like »scrlttr2« from [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/most-useful-additions-in-koma-script)) or [newlfm](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) (for remarks see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/does-newlfm-define-infopathname)).

Answer (score 4):

I found it easier to simply alter the textwidth and margin parameters. For instance, you can insert the following commands in the preamble and change the numbers to tweak the spacing as you like. You can also insert multiple `\\` at the end of the `\address` (or end of the `\date`) gives more space between the return address and the actual start of the letter.

```
\textwidth16cm \textheight21cm \oddsidemargin-0.1cm \topmargin-2.25in
\evensidemargin-0.1cm
```

Comment: Instead of insterting lots of `\\` you could also use `\vspace{<length>}`