# How can I reduce top margin in scrlttr2?

Tags: spacing, scrlttr2

i'm having problems searching for the solution. I'm writing  a simple letter and I see that top margin is too large.
I tried

```
\setlength\topmargin{-50pt}
```

recommended in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29689), but nothing happened.
I also tried

```
\@setplength{refvpos}{5cm}
```

recommended in but it seems to make the body of the letter go up, instead 
of making the whole letter (including address and subject).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\setkomavar{fromname}{%
  \vspace{-\useplength{firstheadvpos}}%
   Me, I  and myself}
```

or if you want to set the KOMA length directly

```
\makeatletter\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0cm}\makeatother
```

However, setting directly `firstheadvpos` should be done in a `lco` file (letter class options).

Comment: I'm wondering why `firstheadvpos` cannot be set via `\setkomavar`.