# scrlttr2: Set refvpos for firsthead and firstfoot differently

Tags: xetex, koma-script, scrlttr2

I use `scrlttr2` and need to reduce the space above and below `nexthead` in general and in particular for one page within my document.
I tried it with the approach [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183783/how-can-i-reduce-top-margin-in-scrlttr2), but it didn't work out. As `nexthead` uses the same margins as `firsthead`, this does not work properly.

I tried it by defining:

```
\setkomavar{nexthead}{my_head \vspace{-0.2\useplength{refvpos}}}
```

It's only taking space from above the header and not from below.

Comment: If you need to change the margins of the second page of your letter, you need to do something like `\KOMAoptions{DIV=20}`. I don't know whether you can put that into the KOMAvar `nexthead`.

Comment: This worked quiet well for all pages. Thank you! Now I would like to change the margin `refvpos` for one page in particular. Is this poossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the margins of the second page of your letter, you need to do something like \KOMAoptions{DIV=20}. I don't know whether you can put that into the KOMAvar nexthead.

To change the margin for some lines, use the environment »addmargin«, which is included in KOMAscript.